# To change a css style depending on time of day (javascript)

Tags: javascript

im trying to write a little .js file to change a css style from `display:block` to `display:none` depending on the time of day, 08.30 to 17.00 display block and 17.00 to 08.30 display none.

Here's what i have so far:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
day=new Date()     //..get the date
x=day.getHours()    //..get the hour

if(x>=8.30 && x<17) {

  document.write('<style type="text/css">#live{display:block}"></style>')

 } else

 if(x>=17 && x<8.30) {

   document.write('<style type="text/css">#live{display:none}"></style>')

};

</script>
```

Do think this is good js plus not sure if using 8.30 would work plus not sure if the last ";" is needed.

Any help on this would be great thanks.

Im now trying this code but does not work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready ( function (){

var dateObj = new Date();
var hour = dateObj.getHours() * 100 + dateObj.getMinutes();

if (hour >= 1600 && hour <= 1800) {
document.getElementById('live').style.display = "none";
 }


 });

 </script>
```

Comment: you realize that `day.getHours()` returns an int value, yes?

Comment: thanks Spudley for the corrections

Comment: No, using `8.30` won't work the way you want it to. The hours value from `getHours()` will always be an integer value.

Comment: Did not  realize that day.gethours() retured int value thanks Joseph amd Neal, so will give that a go now.

Comment: I might have read this incorrectly, but if your `live` style is for something which is truely 'live', then would it not be more correct to check the code server-side, rather than client-side? If the client is in a different time-zone, then it will display the 'live' information when you don't want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `getHours()` returns a whole number (0 to 23).  For 8:30, you will
   need to check `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` accordingly.
2. The last semicolon does not need to be there.

Answer (score 1):

`Date().getHours()` returns an integer. For your code to work you'd have to do something like this:

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var hour = dateObj.getHours() * 100 + dateObj.getMinutes();

if (hour >= 830 && hour <= 1700) {
    document.getElementById('your_el').style.display = "none";
}
```

Note that you should only use this code when the DOM is ready for manipulation.

Although, is this really what you want? JavaScript's Date gets its date and time information from the users' clock. You would probably be better off handling this on the server.

Comment: Ok this is what I'm using now, so I can test at this time, but does not seem to be working                                                                         <script type="text/javascript">
var dateObj = new Date();
var hour = dateObj.getHours() * 100 + dateObj.getMinutes();

if (hour >= 16 && hour <= 18) {
    document.getElementById('live').style.display = "none";
}


</script>

Comment: @dave What do you mean it doesn't work? The condition should be `hour >= 1600 && hour <= 1800`, and this should only be used when the DOM is ready for manipulation.

Comment: It does not seem to hide (diaply:none) the css style by when to DOM is ready do you mean add    $(document).ready ( function (){ to the script i have tried that still no joy

Answer (score 0):

`getHours()` only gets you the hours number, you need to get the minutes as well
try with

```
x=day.getHours()+ (day.getMinutes()/100);
```

about the `;` it is not neccessary after an `if`, but it's good practice to put it at the end of each code line (that would be every other line)